# Texstudio compilation is slow compared to calling from bash

Tags: texstudio

I have a `LaTeX` project that I compile using the following `Bash` script:

```bash
pdflatex -draftmode -interaction=nonstopmode thesis.tex > /dev/null
find -name "*.aux" -execdir bibtex {} > /dev/null ";" 
pdflatex -draftmode -interaction=nonstopmode thesis.tex > /dev/null
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode thesis.tex > /dev/null
```

I call this script directly from TeXstudio with a simple user defined command, `bash compile.sh | txs:///view-pdf` and it takes about ~5 seconds to compile the full document (~300 pages).

The only problem with compiling via an external Bash script is that TeXstudio is not able to catch errors properly. So I made a new user command with the content of the Bash script as

```
pdflatex -draftmode -interaction=nonstopmode thesis.tex  > /dev/null | find -name "*.aux" -execdir bibtex {} > /dev/null ";"   | pdflatex -draftmode -interaction=nonstopmode thesis.tex > /dev/null | pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode thesis.tex > /dev/null | txs:///view-pdf
```

This takes about ~8 sec to run. Why is this slower when both the commands do the same amount of work?

Comment: compare the log files, I would guess you are running a different tex

Comment: calling bash will cause your environment to be set by `.bashrc` so may be different PATH, or different TEXINPUTS or ...

Comment: @Ingmar Are you sure the new title correctly describes the problem? I was under the impression both compilations where performed via texstudio and not via a command line, one calling a bash script while the other used directly specified the commands.

Comment: @Ingmar ... also TeXstudio itself spells its name as one word with no space

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Rolled back the original title and fixed TeXstudio.

Comment: @Ingmar Thanks!

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Checked the log files. they are identical. Also the `PATH` is not modified, I tried calling utilities that were defined in the `.basrc` but texstudio > bash could not find it.

Comment: Just a guess: texstudio does quite some parsing to magic comments and user commands (e.g. to replace `%` with the file name etc.). Maybe it just takes longer to do the parsing with your longer user command?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz just punishment for not using emacs?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Clearly :)

Comment: It could be because of the pdf compression. By default,  Texstudio produces highly compressed files (smaller size). Change setting to lower compression, the compilation will be a lot faster.

Comment: @Dellu Texstudio is not involved in the production of the pdf - it is just an editor which will show the code and the pdf produced by latex

Comment: Yes: but, it comes with the setting on how the pdf needs to be produced. My configuration  for the xelatex is this: "/Library/TeX/texbin/xelatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -output-driver="xdvipdfmx -z3" %.tex". This produces the pdf much faster than the default configuration (which is tuned for higher compression).

Comment: @Dellu You can see both the commands for the bash file and the magic comment in the question. The settings from the texstudio preferences aren't used in this particular case (and neither is xelatex)

Comment: I see. Thank you.